# On which edition of Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets is ancestor first changed to descendant?

Tags: harry-potter, edition-comparison

In the first edition of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, there is a passage:

> "You can speak Parseltongue, Harry," said Dumbledore calmly, "because Lord Voldemort - who is the last remaining ancestor of Salazar Slytherin - can speak Parseltongue."

Here, there is an obvious mistake as Voldemort is the last remaining descendant of Salazar Slytherin. This error is fixed in a later edition. On which edition is this fix first applied?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It was changed before October 16, 2000.

On October 16th, 2000, when J.K. Rowling was asked a direct question about whether the Dark Lord was Salazar Slytherin’s ancestor or descendant, she says it was an error that has been corrected in subsequent editions.

> Question: Harry Potter for grownups again! Is Voldemort the last remaining ancestor of Slytherin, or the last remaining descendent of Slytherin?
>
> J.K. Rowling responds: Ah, you spotted the deliberate error. Yes, it should read "descendent." That's been changed in subsequent editions. (Keep hold of the "ancestor" one, maybe it'll be valuable one day!) 
> <sub><sup>*[- J.K. Rowling interview on Scholastic.com (October 16, 2000)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm)*</sup></sub>

Presuming the information she gave there is correct, that means the error was first corrected in an edition published before October 16th 2000, the date of that interview.